# what's different between these in etherscan?

Tags: events, ethereum, etherscan

I have no idea about this.

I thought it was because of source verify in etherscan, but it wasn't

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you asking why they have the same 4byte hash?

Comment: @foba one has event Name on etherscan but another has not. That's the same functions on each contract instance. I don't know why.